# Dynamically select a version of WHERE clause in SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server

Basically, I want to select one of two versions of a WHERE clause in my SQL SELECT statement, without having to duplicate two versions of the whole SELECT statement.

For example, I would like to specify a variable like @topclients,
and execute the following WHERE clause when @topclients = 'true':

```
WHERE 
    CAST(event_dtm AS DATE) between @start and @end
    and client IN ('client1','client2', 'client3')
```

or execute the following WHERE clause when @topclients = 'false':

```
WHERE 
    CAST(event_dtm AS DATE) between @start and @end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, your `CAST(event_dtm AS DATE)` prevents an index from being used.  This will result in a table scan, so the more rows in your table, the longer it will take to run.  If you just want something to work regardless of performance, use: `WHERE 
    CAST(event_dtm AS DATE) between @start and @end
    and (@topclients = 'false' OR client IN ('client1','client2', 'client3'))`  You may try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the query, which may help performance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
WHERE 
    CAST(event_dtm AS DATE) between @start and @end
    and (
      client IN ('client1','client2', 'client3') 
      or @topclients = 'false'
    )
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't do it. Either way this query returns data for all clients (not just the 3)

Comment: if @topclients is something else than 'false' this will return data for only those 3